# ¿Como se hace una multilista en pascal?

Tags: lista, pascal

He declarado así la *multilista* pero no creo que esté bien ¿Alguien por aquí sabe algo de pascal? (Se que esta obsoleto, pero es lo que nos enseñan el la facultad...)

```
type
    tManager=record
        centername=char;
        totalvoters= integer
        ValidVotes= integer
        Prtylist= tPartylist
        end;
    tPartylist=record
        partyname=char;
        Numvotes=integer;
        end;
    end;
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: ¿A qué exactamente le llamas una _multilista_?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que por multilista te refieres a un Arreglo de varias dimensiones.

Si es así, aquí te dejo un ejemplo.

```
var
   a: array [0..3, 0..3] of integer;
   i, j : integer;

begin  
   for i:= 0 to 3 do  
      for j:= 0 to 3 do  
         a[i,j]:= i * j;  
   ...
end;
```

Es importante que conozcas las cosas por su nombre, ya que eso facilita que puedas encontrar información.

Bienvenido a StackOverflow.

Comment: Hola. He editado tu respuesta para que el código fuente se publique con el formato adecuado. Te sugiero hacer clic en el link de _editar_ para ver cómo se hace. También el editor tiene arriba una barra de botones y la ayuda del sabor de [_markdown_](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) que utilizamos en StackOverflow. Gracias por el aporte.